# Abstract functions

Tags: c++, function, abstract

I have a little problem with an exercise. I have 2 classes :

The first :

```
namespace Abstract{

    class AbstractClass{
    public:

        virtual void setName(const std::string & _name) =0;
        virtual void print() =0;
        void DynamicCastTest(){};

    };

}
```

The second :

```
class ConcreteClass : public Abstract::AbstractClass{

    std::string type;

public:
    ConcreteClass();
    ConcreteClass(const char* a);
    ~ConcreteClass();

    static Abstract::AbstractClass* CreateConcreteClass(const char* a);

    virtual void setName(const std::string & _name); 
    virtual void print(); 

};
```

And the cpp file of the second class :

```
#include "concreteClass.h"

ConcreteClass::ConcreteClass(){
    type = "";
}

ConcreteClass::ConcreteClass(const char* a){
    type = a;
}

ConcreteClass::~ConcreteClass(){}

static ConcreteClass* CreateConcreteClass(const char* a){
    return new ConcreteClass(a);
}

void ConcreteClass::setName(const std::string & _name){
    type = _name;
}

void ConcreteClass::print(){
    std::cout<<type<<std::endl;
}
```

But in my main, when i call :

```
const char* s = "";
Abstract::AbstractClass* a = ConcreteClass::CreateConcreteClass(s);
```

In the compilation, Visual out me an error LNK2019 :

> "public: static class ConcreteClass * __cdecl ConcreteClass::CreateConcreteClass(char const *)" (?CreateConcreteClass@ConcreteClass@@SAPAV1@PBD@Z)

on this last line. Why ?

Comment: Wrong title: this is C++ code, not C ! And please show the full error message.

Comment: What is the "symbol" that the error refers to?

Comment: Edited with complete error code

Comment: Why do you ask this Question the second time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, got it:

```
static ConcreteClass* CreateConcreteClass(const char* a){
    return new ConcreteClass(a);
}
```

is not a declaration of:

```
ConcreteClass::CreateConcreteClass(s)
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out what the fix is, as it's a good learning experience, and I'm 100% sure you don't need to practice copy'n'paste - or you could just wait, because I'm sure someone else will post a "fixed" answer soon, simply because they don't care if you learn or not.

Edit: to clarify. You have declared a static member function in the class. And you have defined a static function that is not a member of any class.

Comment: It's not that they don't care if you learn, it's that they want reputation points for themselves. +1 for a gentle hint in the right direction.

Comment: Hmm it's a static function so i can call it with the 'ConcreteClass::' namespace, then the function name is 'CreateConcreteClass' so for me it's the good declaration ?

Comment: Well, I guess that's my answer not going to be good, as my prediction came true. Please feel free to CTRL-C + CTRL-V Shafik's answer.

Comment: I think we should aim to both provide the answer (or how it could be solved) and explain it.

Comment: @sftrabbit: I have amended my answer with an explanation in words, but not a "copy-pasteable" answer.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `CreateConcreateClass` as:

```
   static Abstract::AbstractClass* CreateConcreteClass(const char* a);
```

but then later on we have this, which is a static function but not the one you declared in your class:

```
static ConcreteClass* CreateConcreteClass(const char* a){
    return new ConcreteClass(a);
}
```

the signature has to match your declaration, and so it should be this:

```
Abstract::AbstractClass* ConcreteClass::CreateConcreteClass(const char* a){
    return new ConcreteClass(a);
}
```

Comment: Right... I dont need to write the static word in the declaration ?

Comment: The issue is `Abstract::AbstractClass* ConcreteClass::CreateConcreteClass`
does not equal 
`static ConcreteClass* CreateConcreteClass`

Even without the static, the return type is not the same.

Comment: @PierreBesses Actually you do not need `static` in your definition but you do need it in your delcaration